# How can I do if seen check on custom splash screen? If walkthrough screen is already seen

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, splash-screen

Im doing a splashscreen first app, to be followed by a walkthrough page if the user first used the app, else go to a welcome page to sign in/ sign up if already saw the walkthrough screen.

My code came from this projects main.dart file: https://github.com/instaflutter/flutter-login-screen-firebase-auth-facebook-login and modified it to this code(from splashscreen tutorial FlutterKart)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:binder/ui/screens/root_screen.dart';
import 'package:binder/ui/screens/walk_screen.dart';


void main() {
   Firestore.instance.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true);
   SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
   SplashScreen(prefs: prefs);
});
}

   class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {  
     final SharedPreferences prefs;
     SplashScreen({Key key,this.prefs}): super(key: key);

     @override
     _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
     }

   class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

    @override
   void initState() {
   super.initState();
   Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () => _handleCurrentScreen(context));
   }

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final logowhite = Hero(
      tag: 'hero',
      child: //code insert flutterkart splashscreen
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
}
 Widget _handleCurrentScreen (BuildContext context) {
bool seen = (widget.prefs.getBool('seen') ?? false);
if (seen) {
  return new RootScreen();
} else {
  return new WalkthroughScreen(prefs: widget.prefs);
}
}
}
```

I want it to show the splashscreen first and directed to the rootscreen if already seen and to the walkthrough screen if first use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably want to use shared_preferences or something similar. Something like this:

```
// add this static variable somewhere
// could technically be initialized during splash screen and added to a Provider or something similar after
static SharedPreferences prefs;

// make `main` async if it is not already
Future<void> main() async {
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  ...
}

Future<void> onSplashScreenDone() async {
  if (prefs.getBool('isFirstTime') ?? true) {
    // you might want to put this at the end of your walkthrough, so they don't miss it if they close the app, for example
    await prefs.setBool('isFirstTime', false);

    // this is their first time, show walkthrough, etc.
    ...
  } else {
    // this is not their first time, do normal things.
  }
}
```